# Valgrind cross compilation for ARMv5tel

Tags: valgrind, embedded-linux

I ran configure with the following option:

```
./configure --target=armv5tel CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --host=i686-linux
```

then ran make

I encountered the following error:

```
m_cpuid.S: Assembler messages:
m_cpuid.S:40: Error: bad instruction `pushl %ebp'
m_cpuid.S:41: Error: bad instruction `movl %esp,%ebp'
m_cpuid.S:42: Error: bad instruction `pushl %ecx'
m_cpuid.S:43: Error: bad instruction `pushfl'
m_cpuid.S:44: Error: bad instruction `pushfl'
m_cpuid.S:45: Error: bad instruction `popl %eax'
m_cpuid.S:46: Error: bad instruction `movl %eax,%ecx'
m_cpuid.S:47: Error: bad instruction `xorl $0x200000,%eax'
m_cpuid.S:48: Error: bad instruction `pushl %eax'
m_cpuid.S:49: Error: bad instruction `popfl'
m_cpuid.S:50: Error: bad instruction `pushfl'
m_cpuid.S:51: Error: bad instruction `popl %eax'
m_cpuid.S:52: Error: bad instruction `popfl'
m_cpuid.S:53: Error: bad instruction `xorl %ecx,%eax'
m_cpuid.S:54: Error: bad instruction `andl $0x200000,%eax'
m_cpuid.S:55: Error: bad instruction `shrl $21,%eax'
m_cpuid.S:56: Error: bad instruction `popl %ecx'
m_cpuid.S:57: Error: bad instruction `movl %ebp,%esp'
m_cpuid.S:58: Error: bad instruction `popl %ebp'
m_cpuid.S:59: Error: bad instruction `ret'
m_cpuid.S:76: Error: bad instruction `pushl %ebp'
m_cpuid.S:77: Error: bad instruction `movl %esp,%ebp'
m_cpuid.S:78: Error: bad instruction `pushl %eax'
m_cpuid.S:79: Error: bad instruction `pushl %ebx'
m_cpuid.S:80: Error: bad instruction `pushl %ecx'
m_cpuid.S:81: Error: bad instruction `pushl %edx'
m_cpuid.S:82: Error: bad instruction `pushl %esi'
m_cpuid.S:83: Error: bad instruction `movl 8(%ebp),%eax'
m_cpuid.S:84: Error: bad instruction `cpuid'
m_cpuid.S:85: Error: bad instruction `movl 12(%ebp),%esi'
m_cpuid.S:86: Error: bad instruction `testl %esi,%esi'
m_cpuid.S:87: Error: bad instruction `jz 1f'
m_cpuid.S:88: Error: bad instruction `movl %eax,(%esi)'
m_cpuid.S:90: Error: bad instruction `movl 16(%ebp),%esi'
m_cpuid.S:91: Error: bad instruction `testl %esi,%esi'
m_cpuid.S:92: Error: bad instruction `jz 2f'
m_cpuid.S:93: Error: bad instruction `movl %ebx,(%esi)'
m_cpuid.S:95: Error: bad instruction `movl 20(%ebp),%esi'
m_cpuid.S:96: Error: bad instruction `testl %esi,%esi'
m_cpuid.S:97: Error: bad instruction `jz 3f'
m_cpuid.S:98: Error: bad instruction `movl %ecx,(%esi)'
m_cpuid.S:100: Error: bad instruction `movl 24(%ebp),%esi'
m_cpuid.S:101: Error: bad instruction `testl %esi,%esi'
m_cpuid.S:102: Error: bad instruction `jz 4f'
m_cpuid.S:103: Error: bad instruction `movl %edx,(%esi)'
m_cpuid.S:105: Error: bad instruction `popl %esi'
m_cpuid.S:106: Error: bad instruction `popl %edx'
m_cpuid.S:107: Error: bad instruction `popl %ecx'
m_cpuid.S:108: Error: bad instruction `popl %ebx'
m_cpuid.S:109: Error: bad instruction `popl %eax'
m_cpuid.S:110: Error: bad instruction `movl %ebp,%esp'
m_cpuid.S:111: Error: bad instruction `popl %ebp'
m_cpuid.S:112: Error: bad instruction `ret'
m_cpuid.S:154: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
make[3]: *** [libcoregrind_x86_linux_a-m_cpuid.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/swathi/Desktop/valgrind-3.6.0/coregrind'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/swathi/Desktop/valgrind-3.6.0/coregrind'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/swathi/Desktop/valgrind-3.6.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Am I missing something?

swathi

Comment: Are you able to x compile valgrind?

Answer (score 19):

Your configure arguments are not right for cross-compilation. To cross-compile with recent autoconf you just specify host and let it figure the rest out. So it would be more like this:

./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi

I also had to modify the configure script by replacing "armv7*" with "arm*". You'll see where.

However, there's another problem. The ARM support in valgrind covers all ARMv5 instructions and a select subset of v6 and v7 instructions. BUT, and it's a big but, to actually RUN valgrind you must use a CPU capable of running ARMv7 code. That means Cortex-A or better.

If you intend to run valgrind on an ARMv5 class processor (like XScale) it will not work and the target program will fault with an illegal opcode.

Sad but true. No valgrind for me.

HTH.

Comment: There's another element to this - in the top level Makefile*.am's, there are specific additions of '-mcpu=cortex8', I replaced them with '-march=armv5te -mtune=arm926ej-s -mno-thumb-interwork -mno-thumb -g' (For my Marvell MV7600 CPU, YMMV) -- and that got me to the point where coregrind/m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S is now the roadblock as it has cortex specific instructions (movw, movt) that don't work with my CPU. Just to see I commented them out and the binary does run without the exception fault but, obviously it doesn't run correctly.. A little closer though.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these facts. When I compiled and ran valgrind 3.12.0 for an iMX25 (ARM926EJ-S with ARMv5TEJ instructions) the only output line I saw was: "Illegal instruction". Is there a valgrind equivalent I could work with?

Answer (score 4):

1. make clean
2. ./configure CC="your path of gcc" --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --host=armv7-none-linux-gnueabi
3. make
4. sudo make install